# Auto Generated Table of Content Like a "Field of Code"

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I have problem with the insert table of content feature in Microsoft Word. It suddenly become like in the picture below. Any solution for this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing `Alt+F9` will redisplay the TOC correctly.

For a permanent fix go to **Word > File > Options > Advanced** and scroll down the **Group** labeled "**Show document content**." Clear the checkbox labeled "**Show field codes instead of their values**."

I've seen a number of posts on this over the last month. I think an update must have triggered the setting of that Option control.

Comment: I have a free Add-In that addresses this problem by automatically switching back to view of field results when you open a document. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#FieldCodesHide